# Why cant I format date to d-m-Y using CakePHP's accessor

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I got a problem with accessor on single record/get.

I have date record with value '2015-10-10'.

```
    //PatientsController.php
    $record = $patients->find()->first();
    debug($record->dob);die;
    //would print 19-10-2016 (today's date)
```

In My Entity/Patient.php
        protected function _getDob( $dob )
        {
            $time = new Time( $dob );
            return $time->i18nFormat('dd-MM-YYY');
        }

If I change `$time->i18nFormat('dd-MM-YYY');` to `$time->i18nFormat('YYY-MM-dd');` it would show '2015-10-10', which is correct but not the format I want.

The question is, why?

For now, I'm using custom finder and formatResults and change the format to d-m-y

```
    public function findPatients($query, $options) {
        return $query->formatResults(function($results) {
            return $results->map(function($row) {
                $tgl = new Time( $row['dob'] );
                $row['dob'] = $tgl->i18nFormat('dd-MM-YYY');
                return $row;
            });
        });
    }
```

Still wonder why cant it be formatted in accessor.

Answer (score 0):

You may be putting **dd-MM-YYY** it should be **dd-MM-yyyy**
Then your code should be

```
public function findPatients($query, $options) {
        return $query->formatResults(function($results) {
            return $results->map(function($row) {
                $tgl = new Time( $row['dob'] );
                $row['dob'] = $tgl->i18nFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
                return $row;
            });
        });
    }
```

Here is the [Official Doc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#Cake%5CI18n%5CTime::i18nFormat)

Comment: Umm.. FYI, the custom finder works just fine. It's the accessor which problematic and is questionable